# Looking for SVG Map Javascript Plugins that Support Line Drawing

Tags: javascript, svg, jquery-svg

I am looking for some free SVG map Javascript plugins that support line drawing. 
I desire to draw a world map with different colors for each country based on intensity. So i choose simple SVG map plugins instead of Google Maps API.

I have found several pretty plugins like http://jqvmap.com/, http://mapsvg.buyhunters.ru/,  [Jquery Interactive Map Plugin](http://codecanyon.net/item/jquery-interactive-svg-map-plugin/1694201). Yet all those plugins don't seem to support line drawing on it.
I need to be able to draw simple curved lines between two points with some given lat and long points.

Have anyone find suitable plugin for that? Or maybe other workarounds to draw line on one of those plugins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose [this library](http://www.ammap.com/javascript-maps/) should meet your needs. You can easily draw line, coloring countries/regions, and plot marker.